# What is the importance of altitude in coordinates (WGS84)

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, altitude

I have these parameter in my system.

```
 <AirportReferencePoint>N27584300 E034233600 43.586400</AirportReferencePoint>
```

What is the use of the altitude `43.586400` in these parameters?

Comment: See https://epsg.io/4327.

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains 3 parameters, Easting, Northing and Altitude. Think of it a X,Y,Z coordinates to draw your point in 3D or space. If the altitude is related to your location on the ground than it is fine, however some objects may be above the ground and the Altitude might be representing height of obstacles. This is an example of how it can be used.

Comment: The altitude is related to a height datum not the ground... what is problematic is that the units aren't specified, ARPs' should always have their height in *feet* as altimiters on aircraft are in *feet*. The vertical coordinate system needs to be implicitly defined. Almost any other coordinate of an object you could (reasonably) safely say that the units are metres like the easting, northing.

Comment: True ! You are right.

Comment: The N and E values are actually packed DMS (degrees minutes seconds, DDMMSSss/DDDMMSSss. It's Sharm el Sheikh airport.